# Two roots of $\arcsin(x)$ in the range $[0,2 \pi]$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

I am baffled with how to write the two roots of arcSin$(x)$ in the range $[0,2 \pi]$, while $x \in [-1,1]$, such that one root can be directly calculated in terms of the other root.

For instance, we can write the two roots of arcCos$(x)$ in the range $[0,2 \pi]$,while $x \in [-1,1]$, as $\theta_1=\arccos(x)$, and $\theta_2= 2 \pi - \theta_1 $.

But how to do that for $\arccos(x)$ ?

Comment: $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2 = \pi - \theta_1$ have the same sine, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: $x = \sin \theta$ might have 3 roots of $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ given $x\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: I mean real roots.

Comment: I mean other than trivial real solutions of $0 , \pi , 2 \pi$.

Comment: OK for that then. Another problem, for your "for instance" above, if $\theta_1\in[0,2\pi)$, then $\theta_2 = \theta_1 - 2\pi \not\in[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @BaronVT If $\theta_1= \frac{5 \pi}{4}$ then $\theta_2=- \frac{\pi}{4}$, which is out of our desired range of $[0, 2 \pi]$.

Comment: Then add $2\pi$.

Comment: In that case we have piece-wise defined function. Right? and we can't write for arcSin as we wrote for arcCos.

Comment: @peterwhy To my actual problem (function of a random variable: Sin$(\theta)$, where $\theta \sim \mathcal{U}[0,2 \pi]$), adding or subtracting a single point from the domain doesn't matter.

Comment: @BaronVT I've edited the question for other root, as 'peterwhy' had pointed that out earlier. So, now the other root will always be in range.

Comment: $\theta_1 = 5\pi/4$ is not in the range of $\arcsin$

Comment: hmm. That's right as well.

Comment: @BaronVT you first comment makes the perfect sense now. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x >0$, then the two roots of $\sin\theta = x$ satisfy $\theta_1 + \theta_2 = \pi$. If $x<0$, then the two roots satisfy $\theta_1+\theta_2 = 3\pi$.

And to correct what you wrote about $\cos\theta = x$, the two roots satisfy $\theta_1 + \theta_2 = 2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing a mistake, I edited the question.

Comment: Again my argument is that if θ1=5π/4 then θ2=−π/4, which is out of our desired range of [0,2π].

Comment: If $\theta_1 = \frac{5\pi}4$, then $\sin\theta_1 = x<0$, then $\theta_1+\theta_2 = 3\pi$, then $\theta_2 =\frac{7\pi}4\in[0,2\pi]$.